# Excel VBA If Else Statement stops code

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

In my Excel File I have a CommandButton which sends an E-Mail if cells E1, K2 and K5 are filled.

Unfortunately my code does not really work.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim nameList As String
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    On Error GoTo cleanup

    If Sheets("Sheetname").Range("E1").Value = "" Or _
    Sheets("Sheetname").Range("K2").Value = "" Or _
    Sheets("Sheetname").Range("K5").Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "The Cells E1, K2 and K5 has to be filled!"

    Else
        MsgBox "All Cells are filled, send E-Mail now"
        For i = 2 To 22
        If Sheets("efforts and risks").Range("BB2").Value <> "" Then
            nameList = nameList & ";" & Sheets("efforts and risks").Range("BB" & i).Value
        End If
    Next
        With OutMail
            .To = nameList
            .Subject = "subject line"
            .Body = "Body Text"
            .Send
        End With
    End If
cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

If the cells are filled Excel shows the MsgBox, but it does not send the mail. Which part of my code do I have to change?

Hope someone can help me. Thanks a lot

Comment: Try first for one recipent, then try for more (maybe the reason is in the way you are concatenating recipaents).

Comment: Just after the line `cleanup:` and before `Set OutApp = Nothing` can you add one more line? `Msgbox Err.Description`. Now run your code. Do you see any error?

Comment: If i only have one recipent it works fine .. thanks. So how do i have to write the code that it takes all the recipent from my list?

Comment: @SiddharthRout .. did it, a MessageBox appears and says "Outlook does not know at least one name" .. so i changed one name and now it works .. thanks both to you for your help :)

Comment: There you go ;) `On Error GoTo cleanup` The idea of error handling is to understand where your code is breaking (i.e if it is breaking) and to handle it appropriately. Right now you are telling the code `If an error happens, take me out of here without even telling me` :D

Comment: You may want to have a *second* error block at the end, specifically for when the mail has been created. Put `Exit Sub` after `Set OutApp = Nothing`, add a new tag (`ErrInMail:`?) and `On Error GoTo` that tag just before `With OutMail`.  Then, *after* that tag, have something like `OutMail.Show: MsgBox "Error in Mail",vbCritical: GoTo cleanup` to display the erroring email for manual review.  Then, you can click "OK" to finish cleanup and exit normally.